# how to check whether push notification send is delivered or not by Parse

Tags: python, parse-platform

I am saving deviceId in parse from the android app.

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/push', json.dumps({
   "where": {
   "deviceId": 22
     },
   "data": {
     "alert": "Yo baby ...  ."
   }
 }), {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "aaa",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "bbb",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result['result']
connection.close()
```

I am always getting result as True.  How can i know whether the push notification has been sent or there has been a failure in sending the push notification to that device  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the documentation (Section 20.7.3. Examples)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html?highlight=httpresponse#httplib.HTTPResponse.read).

For what I can tell, you have to check if the `status` of `connection.getresponse()` returns a `2xx` code ([more here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)),  if so the POST was sucessfull, if not you'll receive, most likely, a `5xx` or a `4xx` code.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am getting response code 200 for wrong device Ids too.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong device Ids"? You're posting (appending) a new device Id (for what I can tell) to an api from parse.com. You are receiving a 200 status code, this should mean that the device id was appended successfully.

Comment: My app hasnt registered any device with id : 22 ..  I am just sending push notification to device with id 22 but that device has not been registered.

Comment: And the content of `connection.getresponse().read()` only returns `True`?

Comment: Yes  ..   Btw for my case, i wont be having wrong deviceIds and i was just checking whether i can figure out or not whether the notification is sent or not if the deviceId is wrong..

Comment: Can't find any usage of `deviceId` in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications). I only took a brief look at it, don't you need to use the `installationId`? It's defined as " Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) for the device used by Parse. It must be unique across all of an app's installations. (readonly)" [see here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries).

Comment: Btw I think you should probably publish to a channel (as presented in the documentation examples linked above) and decide which devices subscribe each channel. This way you would knew that only the devices that have subscribed that specific channel would receive the notification.

Comment: Yes , in my case, this will result to multiple channels as each user will be pointing to different channel. I am using the installation ID

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not sure if there is a way (IMHO it should exist) to send a notification based on a user key instead of publishing to a channel. In the scenario where you only want to notify a single user it's redundant to have to create a channel to a single user even if semantically it's right (for some reason).